# Get the metadata service to see the public IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Please advise how to get the command working after connecting to EC2 instance to get the public IP address -

```
curl http://169.154.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

After creating the Amazon AMI Linux instance and connecting to it, I'm trying to access metadata service to see the public IP address but the command is pending.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-26 ~]$ curl http://169.154.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Although I'm able to run the following command:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-26 ~]$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
i-0393cd83057cb3ccf[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-26 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mis-typed the metadata service's IP address. Use:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```